# Multiple UICollectionViews use same UICollectionViewCell in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am developing an iOS application where I have many views that have UICollectionViews which display products from my website.

How can I display the same UICollectionViewCell in multiple UICollectionViews?

The UICollectionViewCell is in the storyboard inside one of the UICollectionViews.

Thanks!

Comment: create a custom collection view cell class and use it where you have your collection views

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'd like to use One Collection View Cell for All your Collection Views.

So you need to create Custom Class with subclassed Collection View Cell with xib.

So that you can Choose that cell in every collecion views.

Follow the steps :

1. Create Collection view cell subclass as

[image]

2. In all your Collection Views, Select Collection View Cell Class as following:

[image]

3. Then write your own Cell behaviour in that Custom Subclassed Class.

Hope it helps.