# UITableViewCell into multiple View Controllers

Tags: ios, uitableview

I started to develop an app that use two view controllers (VCs). For each VCs I use a uitableview that use the same uitableviewcell. My ask is if exist a same queue between uitableview where to use a uitableviewcell between two view controllers or if i should create a custom queue where i can to reuse the contentview of uitableviewcell

More graph

VC1 - UITableView1 -> UITableViewCell1
VC2 - UITableView2 -> UITableViewCell1

I would like to reuse the UITableViewCell1 in both tables and decrease the use of memory.

pd: the navigation between these vcs is with a uinavigationcontroller.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do it by creating Custom Table View Cell and Use it in all table views.

I'd added solution for the same kind of issue on Collection View.

You just refer the same for your Tableview. You just repeat the same with Tableview cell.

[Common Collection View Cell in all collection Views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36615732/4014369)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thx Balaji, I understand your example but my question is if i could reuse tableviewcell that exist in memory, for example, in vc1 executes dequeue on tableview and this method returns a tableviewcell but when vc2 executes dequeue on tableview and this method returns another tableviewcell and memory use increase because the first vc1 is in the stack of uinavigationcontroller. Thx again.

Comment: Memory will be deallocated when you exit from one view controller. So at that time, all allocated memory will released and loading Second view controller will create new memory instance. Hence, the memory use is same for the two view controllers. It wont be increased when using it in multiple view controllers.